# OSX stat() and libffi

Tags: macos, dylib, libffi

I'm trying to access stat() on macos (10.11) using libffi.  This is part of a new FFI-based foreign interface for SWI-Prolog.  This interface parses the `<sys/stat.h>` header to get the function prototype and `struct stat` type.  However, I get bogus values.  It works fine if I compile the code below and link `mystat` from the generated `.dylib`.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

int
mystat(const char *name, struct stat *buf)
{ return stat(name, buf);
}
```

My suspicion is that I get a wrong `stat` function from `dlsym()`.  Tried both on `/usr/lib/libc.dylib` and `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib`.  That gives the same result.  If I run `nm` on the dylib from the above I get
`U _stat$INODE64`.  `dlsym` doesn't work on `stat$INODE64`.  Looking at libc.dylib we get

```
534_> nm /usr/lib/libc.dylib | grep stat
0000000000001ac5 T R8289209$_pthread_attr_setdetachstate
0000000000001af7 T R8289209$_stat
                 U _pthread_attr_setdetachstate
                 U _stat
```

How do the two relate?  Anyone has any clue what might be going on?

Comment: stat function is bound by the dyld_stub_binder at runtime. Maybe you are getting the first instance of stat function. After the symbols are linked by dyld the calls are made. I'm still trying to figure out a similar situation. MacOS sucks for developers!

Answer (score 2):

The symbol you're looking for is defined in `/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib`:

```
$  ~ nm -g /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib | grep '_stat\$INODE64'
0000000000002ed0 T _stat$INODE64
```

It can be found using `dlsym`:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
(*real_stat)(const char *path, struct stat *buf);

int main() {
  const char *path = "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib";
  int err;
  struct stat st;

  void *lib = dlopen(path, RTLD_LOCAL);
  real_stat = dlsym(lib, "stat$INODE64");

  if((err = real_stat(path, &st)))
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't stat %s: %s\n", path, strerror(err));

  printf("%s inode: %lld\n", path, st.st_ino);

  dlclose(lib);
  return 0;
}
```

The inode number returned by the `real_stat` matches the one returned by `stat(1)`:

```
$  ~ cc stat.c
$  ~ ./a.out
/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib inode: 4335860614

$  ~ stat -r /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
16777220 4335860614 0100755 1 0 0 0 545424 1564436981 1564436981 1565194657 1564436981 4096 448 524320 /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
```

There could be a case when `stat` is declared incorrectly like this:

```
struct stat;
int stat(const char *restrict path, struct stat *restrict buf);

int mystat(const char *path, struct stat *buf) {
  return stat(path, buf);
}
```

The lib does indeed reference legacy `stat`:

```
$  ~ cc -dynamiclib wrong-stat.c -o libwrongstat.dylib
$  ~ nm libwrongstat.dylib
0000000000000f70 T _mystat
                 U _stat
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

`<sys/stat.h>` declares `stat` using special [assembler names for functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html) with `$INODE64` suffix, to avoid clash with existing `stat` (see `stat(2)` for details). The library can be fixed if `stat` is declared to reference the new assembler name with the suffix:

```
struct stat;
int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf) __asm("_stat$INODE64");

int mystat(const char *path, struct stat *buf) {
  return stat(path, buf);
}
$  ~ cc -dynamiclib correct-stat.c -o libcorrectstat.dylib
$  ~ nm libcorrectstat.dylib
0000000000000f70 T _mystat
                 U _stat$INODE64
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

But honestly I'd use `<sys/stat.h>` to pull correct symbol declarations.